# What is the default search path for Ruby gems? i.e. the default GEM_HOME

Tags: ruby, search, path, rubygems

What is the default search path for Ruby gems?  I'm trying to figure what directories I can pass to `gem`'s `--install-dir` switch, so that I don't have to set the environment variable `GEM_HOME` for the gems to be found.

In particular, if I install the gem [jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) via

```
$ gem install --bindir /usr/local/bin --install-dir /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 jekyll
```

then `/usr/local/bin/jekyll` can't find its libraries without explicitly setting `GEM_HOME`:

```
$ jekyll --help
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem jekyll (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:18
$ GEM_HOME=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 jekyll --help
Jekyll is a blog-aware, static site generator.
[ ... ]
```

It seems that ruby itself will look in the directories listed in the Ruby variable `$LOAD_PATH`, which can be augmented by the environment variable `RUBYLIB`.  However, where does the rubygem system search for gems?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Type `gem env`. That will tell you what you want to know.

Comment: it gives three directories eg on osx `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0` . and `/Users/apple/.gem/ruby/2.3.0`  and `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
` .  So which is default for GEM_PATH and which is default for GEM_HOME?

Comment: You can use `gem env gemhome` and `gem env gempath`. To find the user gemhome, you can use `ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir'`